# Namespaces in PHP preventing using of Yii static functions

Tags: php, yii, namespaces

I just implemented namespaces in my small application as outlined here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.namespace

I'm running into an issue where my controller will no longer access `Yii::app()->getRequest();` saying it can't find `include(C:\Users\bkuhl\htdocs\instaLabel\application\protected\components\Yii.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`.

I realize that's because I declared the namespace as application/components.  But I'm not sure how to work around this one...

```
<?php

namespace application\components;

/**
 * Controller is the customized base controller class.
 * All controller classes for this application should extend from this base class.
 */
class Controller extends \CController {
    /* @var $request CHttpRequest */
    protected $request = null;

    /**
     * @var string the default layout for the controller view. Defaults to '//layouts/column1',
     * meaning using a single column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column1.php'.
     */
    public $layout='//layouts/column1';
    /**
     * @var array context menu items. This property will be assigned to {@link CMenu::items}.
     */
    public $menu=array();
    /**
     * @var array the breadcrumbs of the current page. The value of this property will
     * be assigned to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}. Please refer to {@link CBreadcrumbs::links}
     * for more details on how to specify this property.
     */
    public $breadcrumbs=array();

    public function __construct ($id, $module = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $module);

        $this->request = Yii::app()->getRequest();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the relative class name `Yii`.

The most convenient way to do this is by [importing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) the class: just add `use Yii;` below your namespace declaration.

Comment: this is definitely better when you have many occurrences of `Yii` in the class.

Comment: Is that the same as `use Yii/Yii;`?

Comment: @Webnet: That's not valid syntax. Even if it were it would refer to a class `Yii` inside a namespace `Yii`. There is no namespace `Yii`, so it would be meaningless in any case.

Comment: If there's no namespace of Yii, how does it make sense to include `use Yii`?

Comment: @Webnet: `Yii` is a class in the global namespace. You can imagine there's an implied `\\` in front.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
$this->request = \Yii::app()->getRequest();
```

`\` will use the [global namespace](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php):

> Prefixing a name with \ will specify that the name is required from the global space even in the context of the namespace.

Comment: missed it in my answer, when you have many occurrences of `Yii` it'll definitely be better to use `use Yii;` as suggested by Jon, but for the one off case you can use \