# Yii project with namespaces, loading classes from global namespace did not work

Tags: php, yii, amazon-web-services

I am creating an Yii project with namespaced classes. All my classes are stored in projectRoot/protected/src/myNamespace
In this directory I have created class in `MyNamespace/Amazon/Amazon.php`

Controller looks like this

```
use MyNamespace\Amazon\Amazon;
...
function actionIndex() {
    echo Amazon::getBucketFromKey('key');
}
```

That's ok, autoloading works perfectly and this class is loaded.

Amazon.php looks like this:

```
 class AmazonServer {

    public static function getBucketFromKey($key) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'bucket';
    $criteria->condition = 'userkey = :userkey AND enabled=:enabled';
    $criteria->params = array(':userkey' => $key, ':enabled' => 1);
    $bucket = Amazonuser::model()->find($criteria);

    if ($bucket === null) {
        throw new BucketNotFoundException('Bucket not found for this key.');
    } else {
        return $bucket->attributes['bucket'];
    }
  }
....
```

When I run this script Yii returns an error

```
 include(/var/www/yii3/vl/protected/config/../src/MyNamespace/Amazon/CDbCriteria.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Problem is on line with **$criteria = new CDbCriteria;**

**Why this happens? How do I have to call CDbCriteria and other classes from global namespace correctly?**

Call new \CDbCriteria did not help...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234655/namespaces-in-php-preventing-using-of-yii-static-functions

Comment: show your setPathOfAlias() please. It looks you placed it in config..